# Что выбрать между React, Vue js, node js для изучения

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, vue.js

Изучаю сейчас JS.

И следующим этапом хочу посвятить изучению одной из библиотек. React, Vue js, node js.

Но поскольку мало опыта. Хочу спросить совета у опытных.

Задачи в проекте: драг & дроп, api, конструкторы форм, вывод аналитики, панели настроек с ползунками. Просто к слову.

На что лучше сделать ставку. Временной ресурс ограничен, как говориться. И все знать хорошо невозможно.

Из увиденного мной, очень привлёкла библиотека Vue.js, но боюсь ошибиться.

Comment: Самое лучшее - это основательно изучить сам JS! После этого сможете выбрать любое направление что покажется вам привлекательнее. Я специализируюсь на React к примеру, его синтаксис мне больше по душе, но работал и на Vue и на Angular и на чистом JS

Comment: Ну, во-первых, не путать теплое с мягким. Frontend (формочки, шаблоны и в общем то, как у пользователя отображается что-то) - Vue, Angular, React, Svelte. Сейчас лучше Vue 3 и по производительности, и по удобству. Собственно, к фронту nodejs никак не относится - это Backend (чисто логика без внешнего вида, связь с базой и какие-то расчеты). На бэке можете взять что угодно, не обязательно JS. Можете Nest.js взять– хороший.

Comment: Но браться за фреймворки/библиотеки ради изучения JS – ошибка.

Comment: Голосую за vuejs! Во-первых проще чем reactjs в некоторых аспектах, которые лично мне показались немаловажными. Во-вторых - reactjs == facebook == вражеская технология, тем более в свете современных событий. Ну а nodejs автоматом тянется за любым другим *js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поддерживаю комментарии

1. Начни с чистого javascript https://javascript.ru/
2. Потом постарайся понять фишки ecma, https://es5.javascript.ru/
3. После попробуй с чего нибудь простого например jQuery или Vue. https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html (На Vue3 документацию пока ещё не перевели)

Чего новичку делать не стоит

1. Не лезь React, он только выглядит простым, подводных камней там +100500. Утопишься. Для адекватного изучения React желательно иметь ментора.
2. Не лезь в backend, в backend (nodejs) разработчики тебя без опыта некто не пустит. Лучше подучиться на фронтенд, и пойти джуном в компанию. В боевых условиях любой язык программирования изучается намного лучше.

Comment: Я бы ещё рекомендовал https://learn.javascript.ru/, там с заданиями и по мере возрастания сложности)

Comment: А я ещё бы посоветовал забыть про jquery. Его время прошло.

Comment: @Sergey Официально да, неофициально его до сих пор супер часто используют. Особенно в простых разработках. И каждая 5-6я вакансия frontend разработчика требует знания, вы не поверите - мёртвого jQuery.

Comment: Действительно, не поверю:) Да и пятые шестые очереди пусть канут в лету со своей архаикой, туда им и дорога.